# How to "split" a text document or string of text in R so that each word is its own row in a dataframe?

Tags: r, text-mining, tm, corpus

```
documents <- c("This is document number one", "document two is the second element of the vector")
```

the dataframe I'm trying to create is:

```
idealdf <- c("this", "is", "document", "number", "one", "document", "two", "is", "the", "second", "element", "of", "the", "vector")
```

I've been using the tm package to convert my document to a corpus and get arid of punctuation, convert to lowercase, etc. through functions like:

```
#create a corpus:
myCorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(documents))

#convert to lowercase:
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(tolower))

#remove punctuation:
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, removePunctuation)
```

...but I'm having trouble trying to get it in a df where each word has it's own row (I prefer that every word have its own row- even if the same word shows up as multiple rows).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
library(stringi)
data.frame(words = unlist(stri_extract_all_words(stri_trans_tolower(documents))))
#       words
# 1      this
# 2        is
# 3  document
# 4    number
# 5       one
# 6  document
# 7       two
# 8        is
# 9       the
# 10   second
# 11  element
# 12       of
# 13      the
# 14   vector
```

Comment: This is perfect.  Just out of curiousity, is there an equivalent in the tm package?

Comment: I actually don't know that package at all. I'll take a look though.

Answer (score 0):

Well to get all words stacked in a vector I would use `stringr::str_match_all` this way:

```
> documents <- c("This is document number one", "document two is the second element of the vector")
> str_match_all(documents, '\\w+\\b')
[[1]]
     [,1]      
[1,] "This"    
[2,] "is"      
[3,] "document"
[4,] "number"  
[5,] "one"     

[[2]]
      [,1]      
 [1,] "document"
 [2,] "two"     
 [3,] "is"      
 [4,] "the"     
 [5,] "second"  
 [6,] "element" 
 [7,] "of"      
 [8,] "the"     
 [9,] "vector"  

> unlist(str_match_all(documents, '\\w+\\b'))
 [1] "This"     "is"       "document" "number"   "one"      "document" "two"      "is"       "the"      "second"   "element"  "of"       "the"      "vector"  
> length(unlist(str_match_all(documents, '\\w+\\b')))
[1] 14
> do.call(rbind, str_match_all(documents, '\\w+\\b'))
      [,1]      
 [1,] "This"    
 [2,] "is"      
 [3,] "document"
 [4,] "number"  
 [5,] "one"     
 [6,] "document"
 [7,] "two"     
 [8,] "is"      
 [9,] "the"     
[10,] "second"  
[11,] "element" 
[12,] "of"      
[13,] "the"     
[14,] "vector"
```

I think it solves your problem, but depending on the amount of words I'm not sure it's that efficient.